# Exception while using Pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I am new to Pexpect and am bound by the requirement of using it. I am writing a script that logs onto a server and issues a command to login to a device. The command to login to a device is a custom script called "console" and is run by typing "console " at the command line.

I know for a fact that the console script is executable and runs perfectly well when I manually ssh into the server and issue the command. However, while using pexpect, I get an exception saying:

```
ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: console.
```

The snippet of code that invokes this exception is :

```
    console = "console " + devName
    print("Trying connection to %s" % (devName))
    time.sleep(3)
    device = pexpect.run(console)
    k = device.expect([sshNewKey, 'Password:'])
    if k == 0:
        device.sendline('yes')
    if k == 1:
        device_pass = getpass.getpass()
        device.sendline(device_pass)
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? Also, please note that this script is not complete, and I am testing as I write the code.

Comment: Note that pexpect.run(), even if it worked, will just return the output. You probably want pexpect.spawn()

Comment: @user3757614 - hey thanks for getting back ..... i have tried pexpect.spawn() too ..... I still face the same issue. Any idea on what I might be missing?

Comment: The PATH that pexpect is using is probably weird in some way; try exporting the path variable in pexpect to see what it looks like. Also, I'm pretty sure you could use the actual console location (run "which console") to work around your issue.

Comment: Thanks! i figured out the problem myself. It was something else.

Comment: @nsJHDM so what was the problem, dude?